# compiler run and no output

Tags: java, while-loop, shapes

i try to print this shape [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uykop.png)

by using this code

```
    int count= 1 , i = 0 , y =0 , sp = 4 , x = 1;
     
         while (sp >= 1)  { 
           for( i = 0;  i <sp ; i++) {
               System.out.print(" ");              
           }
           for ( y = 0 ; y < x ; y ++) {
               System.out.print("*"); 
           } 
   
           
           if (count ==1) {
               sp--;
               x+=2 ;
             System.out.println();
           }
           
           else if (count ==2) {
               sp++;
               x-=2;
           }
           if (sp == 1 && count == 1) {
                
               count++ ;
              i=0; y = 0;
              sp++ ; 
              x -=2 ; 
             
          }  
         
       }
```

but nothing come on the compiler just run and there is no output

Comment: are you sure that is running inside main function?

Comment: yes it run if i remove this part       else if (count==0) {   sp++;
               x-=2;
           }
           if (sp == 1 && count == 1) {
                
               count++ ;
              i=0; y = 0;
              sp++ ; 
              x -=2 ;      
          }     and print the half shap

Comment: can you `System.out.print(sp);` before the while loops and verify that sp is indeed 4.

Comment: i did that and it is indeed 4 @Shachaf.Gortler

Comment: try adding  System.console.readLine(); at the end , the output of your out might be directed to a windows that closes when execution finishes.

Comment: I ran the code you posted. It contains an infinite loop. Do you also get an infinite loop when you run it?

Comment: when i write this line it give me this massage " console cannot be resolved or is not a field " @Shachaf.Gortler

Comment: yes it is @Abra

Comment: @Abra but it print nothing

Comment: thanks for all of you it was like @Abra say an infinite loop so i just added one line in else if (count == 2 ) {   sp++ ; x -=2 ; if (sp == 5 ) break ; }

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you a goal to strive for in your future mastery of Java, printing a diamond can be done as simple as this in Java 11 and later:

```java
static void printDiamond(int size) {
    for (int i = 1-size; i < size; i++) {
        int sp = Math.abs(i);
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(sp) + "*".repeat(2 * (size - sp) - 1));
    }
}
```

*Tests*

```java
printDiamond(2);
printDiamond(4);
printDiamond(7);
printDiamond(10);
```

*Output*

```java
 *
***
 *
```

```java
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

```java
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
 ***********
  *********
   *******
    *****
     ***
      *
```

```java
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
 *****************
  ***************
   *************
    ***********
     *********
      *******
       *****
        ***
         *
```

Comment: really thank you it is very simple !!!

Answer (score 0):

I just finished playing with it. From what I saw, your problem is that the number of spaces will always be greater than 1 (with how it is currently).

I would recommend having another variable that is the number of rows to print (in the case you gave it ends up being 5 rows of stars). Something like this:

```
int rows = 5;
while (rows > 0) {
  // Your code here
  rows--;
}
```

You'll also have a slight problem when count is 2 with your new lines, but it has an easy fix.